# How to pass variable data to index.html in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to insert a dynamic script into the head of index.html, however the script contains a variable. See below - The variable should be inserted into shopOprigin indicated by {{shopName}} which is obtained through ActivatedRoute in app.component.ts

```
<script>

ShopifyApp.init({
      shopOrigin: 'https://{{shopName}}.myshopify.com'
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be looking to use the `environment` variables inside of you HTML. What you should try instead is after importing the ShopifyApp library into the head of your `index.html` to then call the function:

```
ShopifyApp.init({
   shopOrigin: 'https://' + environment.shopName + '.myshopify.com'
});
```

Into maybe your `app.module.ts` or `main.ts` (before you bootstrap your application). In both files you can import and use your `environment` variables.