# How to pass variable to index.html in angular securely

Tags: javascript, angular, payment-gateway

i have script tags for my payment gateway in my `index.html`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js"
    data-client-key="my-data-client-key">
    </script>
```

my `data-client-key` is showing up in head tags, is it okay or should it be secured? if it need to be secured, how can i secure it?
i have read this post [How to pass variable data to index.html in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50500558/how-to-pass-variable-data-to-index-html-in-angular) but still i wonder is my key should be hidden or not.
and of course i have others key too, like analytics, can i hide it?

EDIT

i added this to my main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  // HACK: Don't log to console in production environment.
  // TODO: This can be done in better way using logger service and logger factory.
  if (window) {
    window.console.log = window.console.warn = window.console.info = function () {
      // Don't log anything.
    };
  }
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js" data-client-key="'+environment.midtransKey+'" ></script>');
} else {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js" data-client-key="'+environment.midtransKey+'" ></script>');
}
```

[image]

the script tag for midtrans not showing up, and i got `core.js:6014 ERROR ReferenceError: snap is not defined`

Comment: The key is going to be used in the frontend anyway unless there is another reason why you will want to store it in the environments, its not worth it. It will be visible to all in the header tag

Comment: i store several keys for this apps, my backend who are deploying this apps to hosting so he only change the key in env

Answer (score 0):

You have two choose

1. Insert this script tag from angular

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
  
const script = document.createElement('script');  
script.src = "https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js";  

if (environment.production) {
    script.setAttribute("data-client-key","my-data-client-key")
} else if (environment.staging) {
    script.setAttribute("data-client-key","my-data-client-key")
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

2. Edit variable from angular by custom key

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace("my-data-client-key", environment.variable)
```

there is no problem to show `client key` because the provider will restrict to use client key per domain etc....

in your case the documentation mention to put client key in html
https://snap-docs.midtrans.com/#frontend-integration

Comment: yes i see, i'm using number 1 so my friend only changing the key in my env, but it doen't show up in my html

Comment: also i use your second solutions, still not showing up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574098/is-document-write-actually-deprecated

Comment: I have updated my answer , I prefer to use first solution  , the document.write is not good to use

Answer (score 0):

Once the Key is to be used in the frontend, there is no way of hiding it. Eventually, it should be in the header tag or somewhere on the page for the required processing to be done

From their [documentation](https://snap-docs.midtrans.com/#overview14), this is a client Key, so there isn't much to worry about. Also Mid Trans accepts merchant Url and other callback URLs, by which they restrict payment and redirection. Assuming these are not as they say, the only thing someone can do is to execute a payment transaction on your behalf into your account.

For Google analytics, there is also not much you can do, but with this, the data you collect can be polluted if someone gets your key, So I will suggest you create a filter on your analytics page and restricting only hits that match your domain. Check out [this post](https://neilpatel.com/blog/protect-analytics-from-hacking/) on how to do that.